# How to get SparkContext inside the executors when run using yarn cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, rdd

I have a driver program where I create the JavaSparkContext and then use the newApiHadoopFile to process custom InputFormat .

If I need to get the JavaSparKContext  inside the CutomInput Format class , how can i achieve it .

My Driver Program :

```
> JavaSparkContext sc=  //create the JavaSparkContext here
> 
> JavaPairRDD<NullWritable, ArrayList<Record>> baseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(args[2], InputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, ArrayList.class, conf);
```

Custom Input Format Class:

```
> public class InputFormat extends  FileInputFormat {
> 
>   @Override   public RecordReader<NullWritable, ArrayList<Record>> 
>   createRecordReader(InputSplit split,TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException,InterruptedException { 
        > final JavaSparkContext sc=    //How to get the spark Context here
```

Comment: just wondering...why do you need SparkContext in Hadoop Input Format?

Comment: The SparkContext is what, e.g. defines and distributes RDDs across the executors. It is a Spark-Master specific entity. This is why you cannot, say, create an RDD from within an rdd.map() operation.

So, if I'm understanding what it is you want to do, the answer seems to be: you just can't.

Comment: Ok .that seems reasonable . In that case is there anyway I can get the broadcast variables inside the InputFormat class  . My Previous qs reagarding this is below .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698882/broadcast-variable-publish-in-spark-program

Comment: why cant you achieve your entire logic using either mapreduce/spark.. i dont think you can make any fruitfull use of spark context in Input format.

Comment: Why I am trying to get the SparkContext was to get the BroadcastVariable inside my InputFormat class . Is there any way to get the broadcast variable inside the InputFormat if I am using the API - newAPIHadoopFile.